# How to work with ETL from old OLTP to new DW, order dates and customer age

Tags: ssis, data-warehouse

We dont have any existing data warehouse, but we have customers (in OLTP) that have been with us many years and made purchases. How can I populate a customer dimension and then "replay" all the age updates that have occurred over the years, so that the type 2 dimension will have all the updates for those customers.

Since I want to populate the fact table with sales and refer to the DimCustomerFK. But when our clients query for data I want those customers to have the correct age. Since if I dont make any changes the customer will have the same age now and 10 years back when he placed the first order.

Any ideas how this can be made?

Comment: Did you store all the updates?

Comment: Well in this case we have all the orders and order dates. We also have the customers date of birth. So it would be easy to calculate the update backwards since I know which date the customer made the first order and based on the customers date of birth I can calculate the age when the order was placed.

Comment: How many customers are we talking about? For large customer dimensions, it's often better to either create mini dimensions that are type 2, or use the fact to track changes in some attributes over time, as a Type 2 customer dim becomes very large very quickly, in many cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem Patrik.

Some options:-

1) design SQL to parse through your customer / transaction OLTP data to create a daily flat file of customer updates. So you will end up with many thousand fairly small files (obviously depending on the number of customers you have and the date range). Name them Customeryyyymmdd.csv. Then create an ETL suite to read in the flat files in forward date order and apply the type 2 changes in order to the DWH.

2) build a very complex SQL query (I'm waving my hands around here as I dont know your data structures so couldnt suggest how complex this would be) that creates an ordered customer change list that you can pass through an ETL SCD component record by record.

Either seems logically feasible given what you have said earlier, but that may give you some ideas to consider that may give you a more concrete solution.

g/l

Mark.

Comment: Ok, I suppose that you mean that I will need to first populate all the old data and then start the "normal" ETL (SCD) that will populate the startdate/enddate with the System:ContainerStartTime.

Comment: Soemthing like that, although I would fake a start/enddate by mocking it up from the filename. So it will look like (hopefully) that you build this system years earlier as they start/end dates should reflect that, though your loaddate/moddate field on the table will show that it was loaded recently.